# KDE and Kali 2.0 - restoring GNOME

Tags: gnome, kde

How do I remove the KDE login screen and restore it back to GNOME?

I ran this command:

```
apt-get remove
```

And it said it removed the desktop.

Yet I still have the option to login to KDE plasma?

How can I just restore it, has if I never installed KDE?